# jQuery - Get value of radio button text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner to programming. I'm building a quiz app with HTML, CSS, jQuery and Javascript. I'm trying to obtain the value of a radio button text with the following jQuery code:

jQuery:

```
$('input[name="radios"]:checked').val()
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="A" name="radios" value="France"><label for="r1">France</label>
```

I've also changed the value of the radio button once the user clicks submit:

jQuery

```
$("label[for=r1]").html("Germany")
```

However, the next time I run the same jQuery command to get the value of the radio button text, it returns to me the earlier value and not the new value. Is there something I am missing in the code?

Comment: `$("label[for=r1]").html("Germany")` this is not changing the value of the radio button, this is changing the html of the label

Comment: what should be used instead? text()?

Comment: See my answer below, to change the value of an input you use `.val` and pass it the new value

Answer (score 2):

you get and set an input's value with the same function.

```
//Gets a value
$('input[name="radios"]:checked').val()
//Sets a value
$('input[name="radios"]:checked').val("some new value")
```

Comment: does that change the radio text too? looks like I have to add another line to change the text output

Comment: Yea you will have to keep the `.html` call to change the label, you just have to also call `.val` on the input element so that it will be changed as well.

Comment: I also want to directly change the value of all the other multiple choice radio text as well

Comment: then you will have to use the appropriate selectors for those labels and call `.html` to set their text.

Comment: yep but thats for the text. It doesn't change the individual values if I use your code above.

Comment: You have to use the appropriate selectors, `input[name="radios"]:checked` will only select the currently checked radio btn, so you will have to make other calls using other selectors to change the others: `$("#someRadioButtonId").val("some new value")` so on and so fourth.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .text() function to change the label's value.

```
$("label[for=r1]").text("Germany")
```

Comment: OP's `.html()` call works fine, so changing it to `.text` is not needed. OP is trying to change the value of the radio button which doing anything with label will not do.